# Primary / foreign key; joining multiple tables using subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a question for an assignment with 5 tables as shown below. I need to write a query with the minimum cost for each sport:

[image]

[image]

2nd column is `equipment_name`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think I need to do a bunch of joins in subqueries with the primary keys being the `id` columns and the foreign keys the `name_id` columns. Is this the right approach?

Comment: What database are you using

Comment: I am using a mysql database.

Comment: What version of MySQL

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a bunch of joins; minimally this question can be solved by one join between the store_equipment_price and the sports_equipment tables - if these two are joined on equipment id then you'll effectively get rows that can give the cost of starting up in each sport per store. You'll need to group by the sport id and the store id; don't forget that it might be cheaper to start soccer by getting all the gear from store A but it might be cheaper to start golf by going to tore B - tho I how I read the question. If however you're prepared to get your gloves from store A and your bat from store B etc then we don't even group by the store when summing, instead we work out which store is cheapest for each component rather than which store is cheapest for each sport overall.

If you're after producing named stores/sports on your result rows then you'll need more joins but try getting the results right based on the fewest number of joins possible to start with

Both these queries will ultimately be made a lot easier by the use of an analytic/windowing function but these are database dependent; never post an sql question up without stating what your db vendor is, as there are few questions that are pure ISO SQL

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not completely clear, I assume you need to find stores from which to buy each equipment for all sports so as to incur minimum expense. Following query will achieve this

```
select s.sports, e.equipment_name, min(sep.price),
(select store_name from stores st where st.id = sep.store_id) store_name
from sports s
join sports_equipment se on s.id = se.sport_id
join equipment e on e.id = se.equipment_id 
join sports_equipment_prices sep on sep.equipment_id = se.equipment_id
group by s.sports, e.equipment_name
order by s.sports, e.equipment_name
;
```

Following **'create table'** and **'insert data'** script are based on your screen images

```
create table sports (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    sports varchar(50)
);

insert into sports(sports) values('golf');    
insert into sports(sports) values('baseball');
insert into sports(sports) values('soccer');

create table stores (
    id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    store_name     varchar(50)
);

insert into stores(store_name) values('A');
insert into stores(store_name) values('B');
insert into stores(store_name) values('C');

create table equipment (
    id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    equipment_name     varchar(50)
);

insert into equipment(equipment_name) values('shoes');
insert into equipment(equipment_name) values('ball');
insert into equipment(equipment_name) values('clubs');
insert into equipment(equipment_name) values('glove');
insert into equipment(equipment_name) values('bat');

create table sports_equipment (
    sport_id         INTEGER not null,
    equipment_id     INTEGER not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(sport_id) REFERENCES sports(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(equipment_id) REFERENCES equipment(id)
);

insert into sports_equipment values(1, 1);
insert into sports_equipment values(1, 2);
insert into sports_equipment values(1, 3);
insert into sports_equipment values(2, 2);
insert into sports_equipment values(2, 4);
insert into sports_equipment values(2, 5);
insert into sports_equipment values(3, 1);
insert into sports_equipment values(3, 2);

create table sports_equipment_prices (
    id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    store_id           INTEGER not null,
    equipment_id       INTEGER not null,
    price              INTEGER not null,  
    FOREIGN KEY(store_id) REFERENCES stores(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(equipment_id) REFERENCES equipment(id)
);
```

Comment: Yes, I need a query that returns the sports and mimimum cost of each sport (1 of each equipment necessary for each sport from the store where it's the cheapest). Thank you for your response.